# where is LoadLibrary A looking for the file?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, loadlibrary

My code uses LoadLibraryA("someDLL.dll"); What is the path it starts searching for the file someDLL.dll?And another question : is LoadLibraryA function case-sensitive?I mean if I have SomeDLL.dll it will not load it?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the online documentation talks a lot about the search strategy.  I'd look there.  As far as case-sensitive, that should be an easy thing to test yourself if it isn't explicit in the docs...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The MSDN Library article [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#standard_search_order_for_desktop_applications) specifies the search order for desktop applications when **SafeDllSearchMode** is enabled, which is the default starting with Windows XP SP2:

> 1. The directory from which the application loaded.
> 2. The system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
> 3. The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched.
> 4. The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
> 5. The current directory.
> 6. The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable. Note that this does not include the per-application path specified by the App Paths registry key. The App Paths key is not used when computing the DLL search path.

Answer (score 2):

[`LoadlLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article specifies search order in Remarks:

> If lpFileName does not include a path and there is more than one
> loaded module with the same base name and extension, the function
> returns a handle to the module that was loaded first.
>
> If no file name extension is specified in the lpFileName parameter,
> the default library extension .dll is appended. However, the file name
> string can include a trailing point character (.) to indicate that the
> module name has no extension. When no path is specified, the function
> searches for loaded modules whose base name matches the base name of
> the module to be loaded. If the name matches, the load succeeds.
> Otherwise, the function searches for the file. [...]
>
> For more information on the DLL search order, see [Dynamic-Link Library
> Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx).

File names are not case sensitive, so NTFS and FAT file names are. It is the [fundamental rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to not assume case sensitivity:

> Naming Conventions
>
> The following fundamental rules enable applications to create and process valid names for files and directories, regardless of the file system: [...]
>
> Do not assume case sensitivity.