# Unhandled exception when trying to load a COM wrapped DLL in C++

Tags: c#, c++, com, gac, loadlibrary

I have an assembly in `.NET`, which I have exposed via `COM` and strongly named.

Upon deployment, this assembly needs to be present in the `GAC`. However, I need to check whether it exists before creating its object.

Unfortunately, even putting the object creation within a try / catch results in `unhandled exception` during runtime, if the assembly is not present in the GAC.

So there has to be some way for me to verify, if the DLL is indeed installed in the GAC before I go on to create the object.

```
HINSTANCE histLib;
    histLib = LoadLibrary("CLSInterOpLibrary.dll");
    if (histLib == NULL)
        return false;
    encode();

    CoInitialize(NULL);
    try
    {
        CLSInterOpLibrary::CLSInterOpInterfacePtr p(__uuidof(CLSInterOpLibrary::CLSInterOpClass));
        if (p == nullptr)
            return false;
        com_ptr = p;
    }
    catch (exception &e)
    {

    }
```

`LoadLibrary` gives a NULL, regardless of whether the library is present in GAC or not, probably needs some sort of path..., and

```
CLSInterOpLibrary::CLSInterOpInterfacePtr p(__uuidof(CLSInterOpLibrary::CLSInterOpClass));
```

..gives an unhandled exception if the DLL is not present.

So how would one check if a`DLL` is installed in`GAC` with`C++?` Or is there a more elegant solution to this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031749/where-is-loadlibrary-a-looking-for-the-file

Comment: Even if I take the library out and put it in the project directory, `LoadLibrary` succeeds, but creation of COM object fails with error as "CLASS NOT REGISTERED" and it throws an unhandled exception.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12673/Calling-Managed-NET-C-COM-Objects-from-Unmanaged-C

Comment: I managed to solve it by trying to call the COM object myself , before trying to get its interface pointer. That way I am able to tell if the assembly exists or not, and handle accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do *not* call LoadLibrary(), the odds that this will work are very small, especially so if the assembly is actually installed in the GAC.  Finding the DLL is the job of COM, it uses the registry keys that were written when you registered the assembly.

You need to fix your error handling, the CLSInterOpInterfacePtr smart pointer type you got from the #import directive turns HRESULT error codes into exceptions.  You need try/catch to catch the [_com_error exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ye3k36s.aspx).  Trying to catch std::exception won't work, _com_error does not derive from it.

Which is good enough to also diagnose a problem with the registration or a missing DLL.  The boilerplate _com_error::Error value you get is REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG (0x80040154), "Class not registered" if the COM server was not registered, something more specific if the CLR has trouble locating the DLL.  The _com_error::Description() method provides you with a somewhat reasonable message you can display or log.  The holy stacktrace is out of reach.

Comment: Thank you. I will try and do what you suggest. Reading into it threw the light that std::exception and _com based exceptions don't mix. What I have done at the moment is try to create an object using CoCreateInstance, and if I am not able to create it, then abandon it altogether. I hope this approach is correct.

Comment: That is no improvement over what you already have.  Using the CLSInterOpInterfacePtr smart pointer is fine, use it consistently.  You need to deal with the _com_error exception not just for object creation but also for method calls.  Exceptions are good, you can never forget to test an HRESULT.

Comment: OK. I shall do the needful this way. Thanks again