# How to use `/DELAYLOAD` on a DLL from another DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, dll

I have a solution with two DLLs. The first one is the "main" DLL. It happens to be an ODBC driver, but I think that is not important for this question.
The second DLL contains all the UI logic for the first one. As the UI is not always needed, I want to use the [`/DELAYLOAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?view=vs-2019) feature which explicitly says:

> The delayed loading of a DLL can be specified during the build of
>   either a .EXE or **.DLL** project.

The main DLL's project correctly references the UI ones. If I don't use `/DELAYLOAD`, everythin works just fine. The two DLLs will be installed into the same directory, so I thought loading one DLL from within the other should be easy. But apparently, it's not.

As soon as the first function from the UI DLL is called, the application (any ODBC client in my case) crashes.
`GetLastError()` yields 126 which apparently means that the target DLL could not be found in any of the search paths.

And indeed, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14031935/9883438) `LoadLibrary()` does have a look into the directory of the calling executable, but not into the one of the currently executed DLL. I'm assuming `/DELAYLOAD` is also just using `LoadLibrary()` under the hood, is that correct?

If I copy the executable into the installation directory of my driver, it works just fine, which proves my assumption that it just doesn't look in the current DLL's directory.

Appart from that, I was also able to make it run by calling

```
LoadLibrary(L"C:\\absolute\\path\\to\\UI.dll");
```

just before the first function of the UI DLL is loaded.
I was also able to determine this path programmatically using

```
wchar_t buffer[512];
GetModuleFileName(hThisDLL, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

But then I would have to cover every single UI call with this logic. So I wouldn't see much advantage anymore that `/DELAYLOAD` has over the "old-school" way of using `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()`.

### **Question**

Is there a simple way to make `/DELAYLOAD` find the target DLL from another DLL in the same directory?

Comment: write own [`__pfnDliNotifyHook2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/notification-hooks?view=vs-2019) and process `dliNotePreLoadLibrary`

Comment: Combine `/DELAYLOAD` with a call to [SetDllDirectoryW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectoryw) to add the directory of the UI DLL to the search path, prior to calling any export of the UI DLL. Nothing else is required.

Comment: Use [AddDllDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-adddlldirectory) (instead of SetDllDirectory) and [LoadLibraryEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibraryexa) to add additional search path to load DLL without impact later DLL load search paths.

Answer (score 1):

There is.  My suggestion would be to create a delay-load-failure hook function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/failure-hooks?view=vs-2019

Basically, you write a function inside your main DLL that gets notified in the event of a delay load failure.  In that function, when the given code indicates failure, you try manually calling LoadLibrary with of a path consisting of the folder in which your main DLL resides plus the name of the DLL that failed to load

How you get the your main DLL from within your main DLL is up to you.  There are many ways.

Something like this:

```
FARPROC WINAPI delayHook(unsigned dliNotify, PDelayLoadInfo pdli)
{

    FARPROC fpRet = NULL;

    switch (dliNotify)
    {
      case dliStartProcessing:           
        break;

      case dliNotePreLoadLibrary:
        break;

      case dliNotePreGetProcAddress:
        break;

      case dliFailLoadLib: 
        {
            std::string newPath = GetMyModulePath();
            newPath += "\\";
            newPath  += pdli->szDll;
            fpRet = reinterpret_cast<FARPROC>(::LoadLibrary(csDir));
        }

        break;

      case dliFailGetProc:

        break;

      case dliNoteEndProcessing: 
        break;

      default:  
          break;
    }

    return fpRet;
}

//
// Set access to our delay load hook.
//

PfnDliHook __pfnDliFailureHook2 = delayHook;
```

Comment: possible and this, but think better use `__pfnDliNotifyHook2` instead `__pfnDliFailureHook2`

Comment: I guess it depends on your scenario.  In a case for which used the above approach,  the DLL in question was in the right path in certain scenarios and not in others.  We wanted to use the default handling if it worked and use this as a fallback.  If you know where it's going to be all the time, maybe not

Comment: default handling is just call `LoadLibrary` for name. if it fail - call `__pfnDliFailureHook2 ` if present. we can not wait when `LoadLibrary` on short name fail but just handle this case based on known dll name. when we understand that need special processing in some case