# Using delay load helper function hooks to specify alternate library directory

Tags: c++, c, dll

How to write and use hooks for the supplied helper function? I want to create a hook to specify alternate library directories to the helper, but I'm not able to implement it by following the docs or other questions I have found. Am I supposed to write a new helper function? Some sources claim that I only need to define the hooks and the behaviour inside the main script.

Answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55497001/how-to-use-delayload-on-a-dll-from-another-dll) question specify some code to be included in the main script, but when in my main script I write:

```
extern const PfnDliHook __pfnDliNotifyHook2 = delayHook;
extern const PfnDliHook __pfnDliFailureHook2 = delayHook;
```

I get:

```
Identifier PfnDliHook is not defined
Identifier PfnDliHook is not defined
```

And many more errors related to all helper variables (PDelayLoadInfo, dliStartProcessing, etc). Of course, I changed the code in that answer from c++ to c.

Other [sources](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170126-00/?p=95265) mention similar approaches, but again not much indication about how to implement. Same applies to the docs for [Understand the delay load helper function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls?view=msvc-170#understand-the-delay-load-helper-function) and [Error handling and notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/error-handling-and-notification?view=msvc-170).

Comment: So, you have an answer, changed it to a different language and it gives you errors. Why do you insist on starting with something that doesn't work? Also, why do you think you need a tutorial from scratch when you have an answer already? Why don't you address the actual errors you get, one by one?

Comment: What? What I meant is that I tried to follow the examples/docs, but I seem to be missing some step/explanation. I know how to write it, but how exactly do I use it? Do I declare the hook inside a function? Do I need to call the hook?

Comment: #include <Windows.h> / #include <delayimp.h>

Comment: Oh god of course, I was missing the delaimp import, I was only linking it. No reference to the library as a requirement in any delay loading doc. Besides this, I figured out how to make it work: Define the hook function, then declare the hooks you want to use as const and declare them as the function you declared above.